# Remote MySQL connection configured from cPanel

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I can't connect to my MySQL database which is held by a hosting provider from my home-network.

I've set up accounts correctly in cPanel so I can connect when I run my php code from their server.

But now I want to access it from home aswell.

I've added my IP (both IP and DNS name..) to "Remote Database Access Hosts" in cPanel.

I've tried to connect both from PHP and directly by:

```
mysql -h [providers ip] -u myuser -p
```

I always get:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (10060)
```

My hosting provider is nosupportlinuxhosting.com so feel like I cant ask them (hehe) but it feels like this would be the way to go to get it working?

I just received the following email from them:
**We are not blocking remote MySQL access.  MySQL is listening on the default port.**

Comment: if it was an account problem, you'd get an access denied error. "can't connect" means the TCP connection is being actively refused, or there's a firewall in the mix that's silently dropping packets. From the same host you're trying to connect from, do a `telnet db.server.whatever 3306` and see if that times out.

Comment: telnet gets stuck on "Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and ends with unable to connect to host with time out... Also 3306 was reported as closed on that host on http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/

Comment: so yeah, there's a firewall 'actively' dropping packets destined for port 3306. if it was just  a closed/unused port, or a normal firewall restriction, you'd get connection refused because the server system would fire back a "no way" refusal notice.

Answer (score 0):

I think your hosting provider is only allowing SQL connection comming from localhost, that's why you can't connect.

Comment: Why would they have the option "Remote Database Access Hosts" in cPanel then? :|

Comment: Maybe they're not using standard ports to connect. Did you verify that the SQL server is listening on the port you're connecting to?

Comment: No, havent, was just on my way to email them and ask.

Comment: You can also just do a port scan using the IP address they provided... =)

Answer (score 0):

Check your ip with whatmyip.com I think your IP got changing... So can't able to connect..

Comment: Yeah, my IP hasnt changed in over a year, it's not that.